# Refactorizing overloads with the same scope but different calls

Tags: c#, extension-methods, overloading

Well I have 3 methods that are overloads, but in it's scope has the same scope except one method call.

```
    public static Texture2D DrawAnnulus(this Texture2D texture, Func<int, int, Color?> predicate, AnnulusConfig annulusConfig)
    {
        InitTexture(ref texture, annulusConfig.offset.x + annulusConfig.radius * 2, annulusConfig.offset.y + annulusConfig.radius * 2);

        Polar(texture, annulusConfig.offset.x, annulusConfig.offset.y, annulusConfig.radius, predicate);

        if (annulusConfig.apply)
            texture.Apply();

        return texture;
    }

    public static Texture2D DrawAnnulus(this Texture2D texture, SectorList list, AnnulusConfig annulusConfig)
    {
        InitTexture(ref texture, annulusConfig.offset.x + annulusConfig.radius * 2, annulusConfig.offset.y + annulusConfig.radius * 2);

        Polar(texture, annulusConfig.offset.x, annulusConfig.offset.y, annulusConfig.radius, (xx, yy) => Annulus(annulusConfig.offset.x, annulusConfig.offset.y, xx, yy, annulusConfig.radius2, list));

        if (annulusConfig.apply)
            texture.Apply();

        return texture;
    }

    public static Texture2D DrawAnnulus(this Texture2D texture, Color? color, AnnulusConfig annulusConfig)
    {
        InitTexture(ref texture, annulusConfig.offset.x + annulusConfig.radius * 2, annulusConfig.offset.y + annulusConfig.radius * 2);

        Polar(texture, annulusConfig.offset.x, annulusConfig.offset.y, annulusConfig.radius, (xx, yy) => Annulus(annulusConfig.offset.x, annulusConfig.offset.y, xx, yy, annulusConfig.radius2, color));

        if (annulusConfig.apply)
            texture.Apply();

        return texture;
    }
```

As you can see the only changing part is the `Polar` method call. The other part is only checks.

How could I simplify this?

Comment: You need to tell us the purpose of the code and explain what it does. It' currently just code without any explanation which makes it off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a single private method and pass the Polar call as an action from each of the overloads

```
public static Texture2D DrawAnnulus(this Texture2D texture, Func<int, int, Color?> predicate, AnnulusConfig annulusConfig)
    => DrawAnnulus(
        texture,
        annulusConfig,
        () => Polar(
            texture,
            annulusConfig.offset.x,
            annulusConfig.offset.y,
            annulusConfig.radius,
            predicate));

public static Texture2D DrawAnnulus(this Texture2D texture, SectorList list, AnnulusConfig annulusConfig)
    => DrawAnnulus(
        texture,
        annulusConfig,
        () => Polar(
            texture,
            annulusConfig.offset.x,
            annulusConfig.offset.y,
            annulusConfig.radius,
            (xx, yy) => Annulus(
                annulusConfig.offset.x,
                annulusConfig.offset.y,
                xx,
                yy,
                annulusConfig.radius2, list)));

public static Texture2D DrawAnnulus(this Texture2D texture, Color? color, AnnulusConfig annulusConfig)
    => DrawAnnulus(
        texture,
        annulusConfig,
        () => Polar(
            texture,
            annulusConfig.offset.x,
            annulusConfig.offset.y,
            annulusConfig.radius,
            (xx, yy) => Annulus(
                annulusConfig.offset.x,
                annulusConfig.offset.y,
                xx,
                yy,
                annulusConfig.radius2,
                color)));

private static Texture2D DrawAnnulus(Texture2D texture, AnnulusConfig annulusConfig, Action polarAction)
{
    InitTexture(ref texture, annulusConfig.offset.x + annulusConfig.radius * 2, annulusConfig.offset.y + annulusConfig.radius * 2);

    polarAction();

    if (annulusConfig.apply)
        texture.Apply();

    return texture;
}
```

Comment: I have to say that I find your calls pretty scarry.

Comment: I totally agree. To be perfectly honest, I don't think I'd go this route myself. Of all the approaches I've seen so far, I believe I like OP's the best - although possibly some refactoring could be done upstream so that these extension methods aren't required to do such gymnastics.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a single private method and decide there what overload to call based on the presence of the arguments

```
public static Texture2D DrawAnnulus(this Texture2D texture, 
            Func<int, int, Color?> predicate, 
            AnnulusConfig annulusConfig)
    => texture.DoDrawAnnulus(predicate, anulusConfig, null, null);

    public static Texture2D DrawAnnulus(this Texture2D texture
            ,SectorList list
            ,AnnulusConfig annulusConfig)
    => texture.DoDrawAnnulus(null, anulusConfig, list, null);    

    public static Texture2D DrawAnnulus(this Texture2D texture, 
            Color? color, 
            AnnulusConfig annulusConfig)
    => texture.DoDrawAnnulus(null, anulusConfig, null, color);

private static Texture2D DoDrawAnnulus(this Texture2D texture, 
                Func<int, int, Color?> predicate, 
                AnnulusConfig annulusConfig, 
                SectorList list, 
                Color? color)
    {
        InitTexture(ref texture, annulusConfig.offset.x + annulusConfig.radius * 2, annulusConfig.offset.y + annulusConfig.radius * 2);

        if (list != null)
        {
          Polar(texture, annulusConfig.offset.x, annulusConfig.offset.y, annulusConfig.radius, (xx, yy) => Annulus(annulusConfig.offset.x, annulusConfig.offset.y, xx, yy, annulusConfig.radius2, list));
        }
        else if (predicate != null)
        {
           Polar(texture, annulusConfig.offset.x, annulusConfig.offset.y, annulusConfig.radius, predicate);
        }
        else
        {
            Polar(texture, annulusConfig.offset.x, annulusConfig.offset.y, annulusConfig.radius, (xx, yy) => Annulus(annulusConfig.offset.x, annulusConfig.offset.y, xx, yy, annulusConfig.radius2, color));
        }

        if (annulusConfig.apply)
            texture.Apply();

        return texture;
    }
```

Comment: Reflection? Dynamics? Ahhhhhh!

Comment: Yep, I might delete that.

Comment: Do you think a polymorphic approach would solve the problem, or is it too much this too?

Comment: Not sure, I'm not going to take any deeper look at OP's code until they fix the question and make it on topic.

Answer (score 0):

You could create helper methods for the repeated parts of the three overloads.

```
private static void InitTexture(ref Texture2D texture, AnnulusConfig annulusConfig)
    => InitTexture(ref texture, annulusConfig.offset.x + annulusConfig.radius * 2, annulusConfig.offset.y + annulusConfig.radius * 2);

private static void ApplyIfNecessary(Texture2D texture, AnnulusConfig annulusConfig)
{
    if (annulusConfig.apply)
        texture.Apply();
}
```

Comment: This should be part of the previous answer and not another one.

Comment: I don't see why. It's a very different approach.

Comment: This isn't a different approach because `InitTexture` isn't even defined in your other answer. It's a method that is missing there.

Comment: `InitTexture` (with all the arguments) isn't defined in any answer; I assume it exists because it's called by OP.